# Phone number not found in context when using Razorpay in medusaJs

Tags: plugins, razorpay, medusajs, medusa

I integrating RazorPay plugin in my medusa.Js application but when I am clicking on the RazorPay payment option I am getting this error in my backend

error:   Phone number not found in context
Error: Phone number not found in context
at RazorpayProviderService. (C:\Study\WD\medussa\mark2\node_modules\medusa-payment-razorpay\dist\core\razorpay-base.js:180:35)
at step (C:\Study\WD\medussa\mark2\node_modules\medusa-payment-razorpay\dist\core\razorpay-base.js:59:23)
at Object.next (C:\Study\WD\medussa\mark2\node_modules\medusa-payment-razorpay\dist\core\razorpay-base.js:40:53)
at C:\Study\WD\medussa\mark2\node_modules\medusa-payment-razorpay\dist\core\razorpay-base.js:34:71
at new Promise ()
at __awaiter (C:\Study\WD\medussa\mark2\node_modules\medusa-payment-razorpay\dist\core\razorpay-base.js:30:12)
at RazorpayBase.initiatePayment (C:\Study\WD\medussa\mark2\node_modules\medusa-payment-razorpay\dist\core\razorpay-base.js:163:16)
at PaymentProviderService. (C:\Study\WD\medussa\mark2\node_modules@medusajs\medusa\dist\services\payment-provider.js:272:71)
at step (C:\Study\WD\medussa\mark2\node_modules@medusajs\medusa\dist\services\payment-provider.js:48:23)
at Object.next (C:\Study\WD\medussa\mark2\node_modules@medusajs\medusa\dist\services\payment-provider.js:29:53)
at C:\Study\WD\medussa\mark2\node_modules@medusajs\medusa\dist\services\payment-provider.js:23:71
at new Promise ()
at __awaiter (C:\Study\WD\medussa\mark2\node_modules@medusajs\medusa\dist\services\payment-provider.js:19:12)
at C:\Study\WD\medussa\mark2\node_modules@medusajs\medusa\dist\services\payment-provider.js:256:107
at PaymentProviderService. (C:\Study\WD\medussa\mark2\node_modules@medusajs\medusa\dist\interfaces\transaction-base-service.js:106:62)
at step (C:\Study\WD\medussa\mark2\node_modules@medusajs\medusa\dist\interfaces\transaction-base-service.js:33:23)
at Object.next (C:\Study\WD\medussa\mark2\node_modules@medusajs\medusa\dist\interfaces\transaction-base-service.js:14:53)
at C:\Study\WD\medussa\mark2\node_modules@medusajs\medusa\dist\interfaces\transaction-base-service.js:8:71
at new Promise ()
at __awaiter (C:\Study\WD\medussa\mark2\node_modules@medusajs\medusa\dist\interfaces\transaction-base-service.js:4:12)
at doWork (C:\Study\WD\medussa\mark2\node_modules@medusajs\medusa\dist\interfaces\transaction-base-service.js:96:56)
at PaymentProviderService. (C:\Study\WD\medussa\mark2\node_modules@medusajs\medusa\dist\interfaces\transaction-base-service.js:126:46) {
type: 'payment_authorization_error',
code: 'cart_incompatible_state',
date: 2023-11-22T04:06:56.959Z
}

It should not show this error

Comment: https://github.com/SGFGOV/medusa-payment-razorpay . See this repo's readme for installation and setup